# Does the Salesforce Marketing Cloud "Integration for Google Analytics 360" product work with Google Analytics 4 (GA4) as well?

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

From what I have read, GA360 is the predecessor to GA4. GA360 has session-based data model while GA4 has a slightly different event-based data model. My business is moving towards GA4 and I want to make sure the "Integration for Google Analytics 360" product is operable with GA4 before renewing it this FY.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that the  "Integration for Google Analytics 360"  product **does in fact work with GA4.**

https://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/HMVaVGR5tUnBtFyKikyMaq